# How to highlight non-empty table cells with CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to highlight non-empty (with alphanumeric values) table cells with CSS? if possible simple ? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:not(:empty)` selector to select none empty cells.If you need to apply different style to empty cells, use `:empty` selector.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td:not(:empty) {
   background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th> 
    <th>Header3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R1C1</td>
    <td></td> 
    <td>R1C3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>R2C2</td> 
    <td>R2C3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R3C1</td>
    <td>R3C2</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kavindra. it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

This code below will highlight all cells and hide the empty ones so it appears that they are not highlighted.

```css
table {
   empty-cells: hide;
}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

td {
    background-color: #f9fcab;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td></td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, d3t0x. Just wondering, isn't there a way to do this without hiding empty cells?

Answer (score 1):

i showed how to make it with css and numeric counter.

Here is link:

```
  codes
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxcwg1o4/